# Windows Batch File that Copy Rated Files

Tags: windows, batch-file, jobs, rating

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I would like to ask if there's a way to copy the files which are rated using a Windows Batch Job (.bat).

The files are photos, and some were rated in-camera. When all of these files (rated and unrated) are copied to my hard drive, I would like to let the batch job automatically copy out the files that are rated into another folder.

I know that my computer has no problem viewing the ratings as when I view the Properties of the rated files, a number of stars are displayed in it.

Any help is much appreciated, and thank you in advanced =)

Comment: What did you have tried until now as code ? show us your code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [tooltipinfo.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat).If the passed item is rated it will have in the output something like :

```
Rating: 5 Stars
```

so you need the tooltipinfo.bat in your directory.Then create batch file like :

(not tested)

```
@echo off

set folder_with_the_items=C:\photos_and_videos
set destination_folder=C:\somewhere_else

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:-d /b /s "%folder_with_the_items%\*"') do (
   call tooltipinfo.bat "%%~fa" | find /i "Rating:" >nul 2>nul && (
        copy "%%~fa" "%destination_folder%"
   )
)
```

As you'll need to change the folder locations at the beginning of the script.